# jQuery: Custom Pagination for Slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I am using [Slides](http://slidesjs.com/), a slideshow plugin for jQuery and am wondering how to implement custom pagination HTML. Currently, when there is only one image, it will disable pagination by default, which is what I want. But when there are multiple images, it will output the following HTML for pagination:

```
<ul class="pagination"></ul>
```

I want something more like

```
<div class="more-views">
    <h2>More Views:</h2>
    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</div>
```

How can I change the way it auto generates the pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise the pagination to an extent, see http://slidesjs.com/#examples

However if you wanted to edit the generated pagination you would have to go and edit the actual plugin source.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate Pagination: `$('#slides').slides({generatePagination: true,`
2. Hide it `$('.pagination').hide();`
3. Use this function in your code:

```
function GoToPage(i){       
    $('.pagination li:eq('+ i +') a').click();
}
```